# GAS: How to write a faster output when listing full folder directory in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to find a better way to write the output in Google sheet. I am using the following code below and finding that it writes the output line by line and it takes a long time. Is there a way to optimize this? Your input is appreciated.

Main function 1: List all folders, & write into the current sheet.

```
function listFolders(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('SHEETNAME');
  var folderId = sheet.getRange('B1').getValue();
  getFolderTree(folderId, false);
};

// Main function 2: List all files & folders, & write into the current sheet.
function listAll(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('SHEETNAME');
  var folderId = sheet.getRange('B1').getValue();
  getFolderTree(folderId, true); 
};

// Get Folder Tree
function getFolderTree(folderId,listAll) {
  try {
    
    /* Initialise the sheet */
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('SHEETNAME');
    sheet.getRange('A3:H').clear();
    var folderId = sheet.getRange('B1').getValue();    
    sheet.getRange(2,1,1,8).setValues([["Folder Path", "Name", "URL", "Access", "Owner","Viewers", "Editors", "Date"]]);
    
    if (folderId == "") {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.alert('Error','Please enter the Parent FolderId in Cell B1!', ui.ButtonSet.OK)
    return;
    }
    
    var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
    var parentFolderName = parentFolder.getName();
    
    var parentFiles = parentFolder.getFiles();
    while (parentFiles.hasNext()) {
      var parentFile = parentFiles.next();
     
      var data = [
      parentFolderName, // Full Path
        //      parentFolder.getName() + "/" + parentFile.getName() + "/" + parentFile.getName(),
      parentFile.getName(),
      parentFile.getUrl(),
      parentFile.getAccess(Session.getActiveUser()),
      parentFile.getOwner().getEmail(),
      parentFile.getViewers().map(function(e){return [e.getEmail()]}).join(","),
      parentFile.getEditors().map(function(e){return [e.getEmail()]}).join(","),
      parentFile.getDateCreated()
      ];
   
      /* Write data */
      sheet.appendRow(data);
    }
    
    /* Get files and folders */
    getChildFolders(parentFolderName,parentFolder, data, sheet, listAll);
  
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString());
  }
}

// Get the list of files and folders and their metadata in recursive mode
//function getChildFolders(parentName, parentFolder, data, sheet, listAll)

function getChildFolders(parentFolderName, parentFolder,data,sheet, listAll) {
    
      var childFolders = parentFolder.getFolders();
      
      var values = [];
      
      // List folders inside the folder
  while (childFolders.hasNext()) {
    var childFolder = childFolders.next();
    var childFolderName = childFolder.getName();

    var data = [
    parentFolderName + "/" + childFolderName,  //Full Path
    childFolderName,
    childFolder.getUrl(),
    childFolder.getAccess(Session.getActiveUser()),
    childFolder.getOwner().getEmail(),
    childFolder.getViewers().map(function(e){return [e.getEmail()]}).join(","),
    childFolder.getEditors().map(function(e){return [e.getEmail()]}).join(","),
    childFolder.getDateCreated()
    ];
  
    /* Write data */
    sheet.appendRow(data);
  
  // List files inside the folder
  var files = childFolder.getFiles();
  
  while (listAll & files.hasNext()) {
    var childFile = files.next();
    var childFileName = childFile.getName(); 

    var data = [parentFolderName + "/" + childFolderName, // Path
                childFileName,      
                childFile.getUrl(),
                childFile.getAccess(Session.getActiveUser()),
                childFile.getOwner().getEmail(),
                childFile.getViewers().map(function(e){return [e.getEmail()]}).join(","),
                childFile.getEditors().map(function(e){return [e.getEmail()]}).join(","),
                childFile.getDateCreated()
                    ];

    /* Write data */
    sheet.appendRow(data);
   }
  /* Recursive call of the subfolder */
  getChildFolders(parentFolderName + "/" + childFolderName, childFolder, data, sheet, listAll); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of appending data row by row, you can have an array and store data in it and setvalues in a batch.

Try the following code:

```
function listFolders() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('SHEETNAME');
    var folderId = sheet.getRange('B1').getValue();
    var dataArr = [];
    dataArr.push(["Folder Path", "Name", "URL", "Access", "Owner", "Viewers", "Editors", "Date"]);
    getFolderTree(folderId, false, dataArr);
    sheet.getRange(2, 1, dataArr.length, dataArr[0].length).setValues(dataArr);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
};

// Main function 2: List all files & folders, & write into the current sheet.
function listAll() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('SHEETNAME');
    var folderId = sheet.getRange('B1').getValue();
    var dataArr = [];
    dataArr.push(["Folder Path", "Name", "URL", "Access", "Owner", "Viewers", "Editors", "Date"]);
    getFolderTree(folderId, true, dataArr);
    sheet.getRange(2, 1, dataArr.length, dataArr[0].length).setValues(dataArr);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
};

// Get Folder Tree
function getFolderTree(folderId, listAll, dataArr) {
    try {

        /* Initialise the sheet */
        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('SHEETNAME');
        sheet.getRange('A3:H').clear();
        var folderId = sheet.getRange('B1').getValue();
        //sheet.getRange(2,1,1,8).setValues([["Folder Path", "Name", "URL", "Access", "Owner","Viewers", "Editors", "Date"]]);

        if (folderId == "") {
            var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
            ui.alert('Error', 'Please enter the Parent FolderId in Cell B1!', ui.ButtonSet.OK)
            return;
        }

        var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
        var parentFolderName = parentFolder.getName();

        var parentFiles = parentFolder.getFiles();
        while (parentFiles.hasNext()) {
            var parentFile = parentFiles.next();

            var data = [
                parentFolderName, // Full Path
                //      parentFolder.getName() + "/" + parentFile.getName() + "/" + parentFile.getName(),
                parentFile.getName(),
                parentFile.getUrl(),
                parentFile.getAccess(Session.getActiveUser()),
                parentFile.getOwner().getEmail(),
                parentFile.getViewers().map(function (e) {
                    return [e.getEmail()]
                }).join(","),
                parentFile.getEditors().map(function (e) {
                    return [e.getEmail()]
                }).join(","),
                parentFile.getDateCreated()
            ];

            /* Write data */
            //sheet.appendRow(data);
            dataArr.push(data);
        }

        /* Get files and folders */
        getChildFolders(parentFolderName, parentFolder, data, sheet, listAll, dataArr);

    } catch (e) {
        Logger.log(e.toString());
    }
}

// Get the list of files and folders and their metadata in recursive mode
//function getChildFolders(parentName, parentFolder, data, sheet, listAll)

function getChildFolders(parentFolderName, parentFolder, data, sheet, listAll, dataArr) {

    var childFolders = parentFolder.getFolders();

    var values = [];

    // List folders inside the folder
    while (childFolders.hasNext()) {
        var childFolder = childFolders.next();
        var childFolderName = childFolder.getName();

        var data = [
            parentFolderName + "/" + childFolderName, //Full Path
            childFolderName,
            childFolder.getUrl(),
            childFolder.getAccess(Session.getActiveUser()),
            childFolder.getOwner().getEmail(),
            childFolder.getViewers().map(function (e) {
                return [e.getEmail()]
            }).join(","),
            childFolder.getEditors().map(function (e) {
                return [e.getEmail()]
            }).join(","),
            childFolder.getDateCreated()
        ];

        /* Write data */
        //sheet.appendRow(data);
        dataArr.push(data);

        // List files inside the folder
        var files = childFolder.getFiles();

        while (listAll & files.hasNext()) {
            var childFile = files.next();
            var childFileName = childFile.getName();

            var data = [parentFolderName + "/" + childFolderName, // Path
                childFileName,
                childFile.getUrl(),
                childFile.getAccess(Session.getActiveUser()),
                childFile.getOwner().getEmail(),
                childFile.getViewers().map(function (e) {
                    return [e.getEmail()]
                }).join(","),
                childFile.getEditors().map(function (e) {
                    return [e.getEmail()]
                }).join(","),
                childFile.getDateCreated()
            ];

            /* Write data */
            //sheet.appendRow(data);
            dataArr.push(data);
        }
        /* Recursive call of the subfolder */
        getChildFolders(parentFolderName + "/" + childFolderName, childFolder, data, sheet, listAll, dataArr);
    }
};
```